# Best way access element in an IEnumerable type

Tags: c#

The language I use is C#.

Say we have a IEnumerable, which is the result of a linq query. T is an anonymous type.
What is the best way if we want to access the elements of this type.

I think that there are two ways.

1) Convert the IEnumerable to List and then access the elements.

```
List<T> list = result.ToList();
for(int rowIndex=0; rowIndex<list.Count; rowIndex++)
{
    double x = list[rowIndex].val;
}
```

2)

```
for(int rowIndex=0; rowIndex<result.Count(); rowIndex++)
{
    double x = result.ElementAt(rowIndex).val;
}
```

The reason why I am thinking something like the above is that except from accessing the elements of the IEnumerable, I need their indices. In other words, if an element is the first, the second etc.

Thanks in advance for any help !

Comment: I still don't understand the problem. You don't need to create collection, use an `int index=0` and increase it in a `foreach`. Then you have the index and the element.

Comment: What is wrong with `foreach` using the `IEnumerable`?

Comment: How can `T` be an anonymous type?

Comment: This sounds like an ideal candidate for [SmartEnumerable](http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/miscutil/usage/smartenumerable.html).

Comment: @crashmstr I need the index of the element.

Comment: @Jeroen T is an anonymous type, because I query a list of objects of a certain type and I select using linq a subset of the properties of each object of this certain type.

Comment: @ChristosPaisios: Side-note: apart from my solution below you could  also include the index in the anonymous type as property. There's [an overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534869(v=vs.110).aspx) that provides the index in `Select`.

Comment: @Tim, thanks for providing another solution !

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You don't need to create collection, use an `int` variable which is 0 and increase it in a `foreach`. Then you have the index and the element.

```
int index = 0;
foreach(var x in result)
{
    // x is the element and index the current index
    Console.WriteLine("Val:{0} Index:{1}", x.val, index);
    index ++;
}
```